# Adding label on x axis in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis-labels

I would like to add a label on the x axis of my bar chart. Here is how I generated my bar chart in R:

```
x <- c(10,10,10,10,10)
y <- c(45.57, 8, 8, 14,0.5 )
barplot(y, x)
barplot(y, x, xaxt="n")
```

I know adding `xaxt="n"` allows me to edit my labels, but when I tried the following commands, the text was squeezed into a single side of the graph and not on the corresponding bar in x-axis:

```
 axis(side = 1, 
  at=1:5, 
  lab=c(   "LT", 
           "LB", 
           "LBN", 
           "CD",
           "MLE"
        ),
  las=3)
```

Comment: see the `names.arg` argument in `?barplot` ...

Answer (score 0):

That's because you did not read what the `barplot` function returns (besides having a side-effect of calling the graphics device.) It returns the locations in user coordinates, so use thos fo the a`at` values:

```
?barplot  # Read "Value" section
 barloc <- barplot(y, x, xaxt="n")
  axis(side = 1, 
   at=barloc, 
   lab=c(   "LT", 
            "LB", 
            "LBN", 
            "CD",
            "MLE"
         ),
   las=3)
```